# Apply "sapply" function in R for different variables in one function

Tags: r, sapply

How to use function "sapply" with different variables in one function? 
For example, it is simple to use it with one variable, as is in the following example:

```
x1 <- c(1,2,3)
sapply(x1, function(x) dnorm(x, mean=2, sd=1))
```

However, how to apply different variables to some function with sapply? Please find the example below:

```
 x1 <- c(1,2,3)
 mean1 <- c(1,2,3)
 sd1 <- c(1,2,3)
 ### ???
 sapply( c(x1, mean1, sd1), function (x, mean, sd) dnorm(x = x1, mean = mean1, sd=sd1)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You're looking for `mapply`.

Comment: Thank you! Is it also work for lapply (with the lists)?

Comment: That is, if  mapply is a multivariate version of sapply, what is for lapply?

Comment: `sapply` _is_ `lapply`, it just does some extra processing on the results.

Comment: This question is subset of [R Grouping functions: sapply vs. lapply vs. apply. vs. tapply vs. by vs. aggregate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/r-grouping-functions-sapply-vs-lapply-vs-apply-vs-tapply-vs-by-vs-aggrega)